# Custom Authorization - Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I have a web api for which i would need to implement custom authentication and authorization. The authorization should be defined by Resource and Action as shown below:

```
[Authorize("users","view")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync()
{
}
```

Is there any way i can use custom authorization filter and implement this?

Also, the web api is protected by client certificate and the caller is identifier by key which is passed in the request header. The Key is authenticated using a custom authentication filter.

Regarads,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create custom Authorization and put on controller or method that needs to be authorized.

sample example is as below

```
public class CustomAuthorize : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private string Resource { get; set; }
        private string Action { get; set; }
        public CustomAuthorize(string resource, string action)
        {
            Resource = resource;
            Action = action;
        }
        public override void OnAuthorization(
               System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
            //Check your post authorization logic using Resource and Action
            //Your logic here to return authorize or unauthorized response 
        }
    }
```

Here you can do your custom authorization logic and sample controller will look like this

```
public class DoThisController : ApiController
{
    [CustomAuthorize("users","view")]// for specific methods
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Sample Authorized";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you did not understand what my real question was. I want to write Custom Authorization attribute that can accept two parameters - Resource and Action. I should be able to define authorization of a method by providing the resource which the user is trying to access and the action which the user is performing on the resource.

Comment: @SillyJohn please check the edited answer for your specific purpose.

Comment: @SillyJohn please check with your requirement, as when you do a vote down please give a proper reason  why the solution was not useful to you . I have changed to specific your purpose, is this helpful?

Comment: why do I have an error The type or namespace name 'CustomAuthorizeAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ....TestController.cs